# pl sql how can i fetch records with max values from another column by each room number

Tags: oracle

table

| room-number | entry-number | electricity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| n100 | 5 | 100 |
| n100 | 4 | 90 |
| n200 | 2 | 75 |
| n200 | 1 | 69 |
| n300 | 6 | 150 |
| n300 | 5 | 111 |

result should be

| room-number | electricity |
| --- | --- |
| n100 | 100 |
| n200 | 75 |
| n300 | 150 |

Comment: Have you tried writing any SQL code yet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure because I haven't tried it but

try this.

```
SELECT room-number, MAX(electricity) FROM table group by room-number
```

Comment: Put double quotes around `room-number`.